# How do I *keep* overflow as scroll or auto?

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

Some sites (notably twitter) like to set overflow:hidden, typically on either body or html, particularly when they pop up a modal window.  With a chrome extension, I've set it to scroll as !important, but ... after a delay, it changes.  Is there a way (short of turning off javascript entirely) to keep the overflow attribute where I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should share your code - however I think the best way to do this would be to listen to changes to the DOM (in the `content` script of your extension) and re-set the `overflow` to `auto`/`scroll`. You can use `MutationObserver`:

```
 let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    // Code here
 });
 observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: Ah; I wasn't clear.  I tried using an existing extension (I think it stylistic.)  I want to do this as a reader, not a page author.  But I suppose creating an entirely new extension so I can run custom javascript may end up as the least bad answer.